# Which program can I use to create a UI on mac as a beginner?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, gui

I've downloaded the program Httrack for mac, but it runs in the Terminal.  I thought it would be a good way to learn to program by making a UI for it, since all the running parts are already there right?

Is there a program I can use to make a simple UI for it, without much prior knowledge?  I've downloaded the Snow Leopard developer pack, so I've got a bunch of stuff like Xcode, Dashcode, Instruments, Interface Builder- not really sure where to start.  Maybe this isn't a beginner project..

Comment: I wonder if you might have more luck asking this on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: What language would you prefer?

Comment: I don't know; really the only ones I've had experience with are C and Matlab.  Guess I'll wikipedia them and see which one sounds more interesting-
Maybe I'll try stackoverflow.com too, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few choices, if you are familiar with some kind of programming language start there and see if they have a GUI library.
A few examples:

- If you'd like to use python: [tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)
- If you'd like to use perl: [perl/Tk](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2001/03/gui.html)
- If you'd like to use ruby: [Glade](http://xrob.wordpress.com/2007/04/20/creating-a-gui-application-using-glade-and-ruby/)